# Chart.JS Charting Similar Data, with Different Labels

Tags: charts, chart.js

I have a DB query that returns how many customers were brought in from a referral source during a specific time frame, which makes this tricky. Here is a sample dataset:

```
{
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": [
      "Drive By/ Location ,",
      "Ins Co/ Web Site ,",
      "Google/Internet ,",
      "OTHER ,",
      "SOCIAL MEDIA ,",
      "RETURN PT "
    ],
    "datasets": [
      {
        "label": "2023-04-01 00:00:00",
        "data": [
          13,
          5,
          40,
          4,
          1,
          13
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
      },
      {
        "label": "2023-03-10 00:00:00",
        "data": [
          13,
          2,
          40
          1,
          12
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
      },
      {
        "label": "2023-02-10 00:00:00",
        "data": [
          13,
          5,
          44,
          4
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 255, 64)"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Naturally I know I mangled it, which I did on purpose. The issue is that if I don't eliminate results that have null values month to month, then there are hundreds of labels, but when I restrict the results to only those that have results, maybe in February there was no "SOCIAL MEDIA" numbers.

So as I build the `labels`, I can't just keep adding to an array, because then the data won't line up since some will have 5 results, and some 3, and another 10. I could insert null values for things that were seen earlier, but if the 3rd month I get a referral from John, then I would need to go back and modify the first 2 months to insert null values for John...

To complicate things just a tad more, I would love to be able to track these at multiple locations on a single chart. For instance, showing all February referral sources across 10 locations, which would naturally have different names per location, `John, Bill, Jessica...`